# ES6 Map sorting issue with Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, sorting, ecmascript-6

I am still learning javascript. I am trying to sort an Map object in JavaScript.
I simplified the code into

```
data = new Map();
data.set('1', {id:1, time: 1});
data.set('2', {id:2, time: 2});
data.set('3', {id:3, time: 3});
data.set('4', {id:4, time: 4});
data.set('5', {id:5, time: 5});
data.set('6', {id:6, time: 6});
data.set('7', {id:7, time: 7});
data.set('8', {id:8, time: 8});
data.set('9', {id:9, time: 9});
data.set('10', {id:10, time: 10});
data.set('11', {id:11, time: 11});
data.set('12', {id:12, time: 12});
newdata = new Map([...data.entries()].sort((a, b) => {return a[1].time < b[1].time;}));
// The last line of code is obtained from another stackoverflow question.
```

If you run this whole script in Chrome, it doesn't do what it is supposed to do, however it works in Firefox.

Anyone have any ideas? or have I made a silly mistake such as a typo?

Comment: Your browser may be outdated and not supporting some of the ES6 features.

Comment: Silly mistake yes, typo no :-) It's got nothing to do with the map.

Comment: Which question did you get that last line from? Please link it (so that I can bash it)

Comment: @ManishJangir it is the latest version.

Comment: I am curious, can anyone please post your result for newdata?

Comment: @Bergi  Thanks for linking the question.